# Customize ant design with craco for existing react template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, antd, craco

I'm using a ready-made react template starter kit in a project. **Sass** is used in the template and **craco** is preferred for configuration. As a UI library, there is **reactstrap**.

But I need to include **ant design** in the project. But ant design uses **less**. What I want is to customize **ant design** and make **css** variables look like the existing template's design.
My craco.config file currently looks like the following. I tried to config as written in Ant design's documentation but I couldn't do it.

Here is my excist **craco.config.js**:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: "react-scripts",
  style: {
    sass: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: ["node_modules", "src/assets"],
        },
      },
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("postcss-rtl")()],
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/assets"),
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/components"),
      "@layouts": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/layouts"),
      "@store": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/redux"),
      "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/scss"),
      "@configs": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/configs"),
      "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utility/Utils"),
      "@hooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utility/hooks"),
      "@images": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/images"),
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply add [own less file](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-less-file) with own variables definition?

Comment: No, i didn't try. Could you give me more detailed information?

Comment: Hey @Hashim, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [craco-antd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-antd) plugin.
You'll need to add it to the plugins, as follow:

```
const CracoAntdPlugin = require('craco-antd');

module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoAntdPlugin,
            options: {
                customizeThemeLessPath: path.join(__dirname, 'src/theme/variables.less'),
                babelPluginImportOptions: { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true },
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

**"src/theme/variables.less"** is the path to the file you're overwriting antd less variables. This one will look like this:

```
@import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';

@primary-color: #0c2346;
@success-color: #1dd3b0;
@error-color: #ef476f;
@link-color: #1890ff;
@warning-color: #f07f34;
```